# Integrating in a simulation model

Tags: modelica, dymola, integrator

[image]

I'm using the program Dymola in this case. As you can see in the figure, we have our temperature goal (refTemp) and we are comparing this temperature with a temperature in the system(KvvTemp). Our goal is to differentiate these temperatures, then multiplying the difference with a small number so our value will become between 0-1 before entering the intergrator. Now to my question, how is it possible for the integrator's output to be the temperature we want to send in to the system (y1)? Is there any explanation on how it is possible to set the temperature that will enter the system(y1) through the intergrator?

Comment: Could you please explain the context of your problem? What you have shown in the figure looks to me like an integral controller. The temperature response of the closed-loop system (system + controller + feedback) depends on the dynamics of you "plant model" which you have not shown.

Comment: Im working with a district heating model. My goal is to control the temperature, as you can see in the figure, and find a smooth solution to integrate the temperature and still having temperature as the output from the integrator. Im thinking of a PI-controller instead of the integrator, but Im not sure it will work smoothly. The problem is when I dont use any controller and just insert the required temperature directly into the system the result is scattering. So my idea was to use the integrator to make the result smoother.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at the controls in the Annex60 library: https://github.com/iea-annex60/modelica-annex60/tree/master/Annex60/Controls

Comment: Ok. You are trying to control the forward DH temperature to 80 °C by adjusting the heat input to your system (DH boiler or the like). The smoothing you look for should be a part of the plant (boiler) not shown. When the controller changes the heat input the plant dynamics will ensure that the controlled temperature doesn't change immediately. In that case you can use a PI controller. If your plant model doesn't have any dynamics you could apply a low-pass filter at the output of your controller to represent actuator dynamics.